# Get mxGraph vertix all object data

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I'm new to mxGraph, I want to get the vertex (cell) all related data when choosing it (clicking it), if you clicked the properties of a certain cell you will get its data, how can I get it with the code?
I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754405/how-to-get-the-id-of-an-maxgraph-cells-content#), but show this error
[image]

[image: this image to descripe question]

> Update:
>   this code gives me an object of the clicked cell (mxGraph v3.9.8).

```
mxGraph.prototype.addListener(mxEvent.CLICK, function(sender, event){
   var mouseEvent = event.getProperty("event");
   var selectedCell = event.getProperty("cell");
   console.log(selectedCell);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this helps me

```js
mxGraph.prototype.addListener(mxEvent.CLICK, function(sender, event){
   var mouseEvent = event.getProperty("event");
   var selectedCell = event.getProperty("cell");
   console.log(selectedCell);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called 'showProperties' belonging to the mxEditor class. In there you can see how it works to show (and get) the properties of a cell.

Be sure the user object for these properties is a node, i.e.:

```
var doc = mxUtils.createXmlDocument();
var node = doc.createElement('MyNode');
node.setAttribute('label', 'My Name');
node.setAttribute('notes', 'My cell notes');
```

Comment: this will help with creating a new element with code, but I have an editor like this
http://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/workfloweditor.html
so I want to get data of each object of the toolbar when I choose one of them to draw.

Comment: do you know how to enable save and auto save in this library ??
also extracting graph in XML?